# Get Active Directory Value from external AD

Tags: azure, active-directory, ldap, adfs

We have a Web Application which runs in Microsoft Azure.
This Web App needs to get AD User Values from an extern Active Directory which is located at our Customer Network. We have the Windows Login and need to get a specific value from this external AD. What would be the best way to make this possible? I heard you can do it with ADFS. Would it also be possible to implement this with Azure?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure you can use an [Azure relay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-what-is-it) that enables you to securely expose services that reside within a corporate enterprise network to the public cloud, without having to open a firewall connection.

The on-premises service would then access AD via LDAP calls using a C# library such as DirectoryServices.

ADFS only provides attributes (as claims) from AD when you authenticate.

Or you could access AD directly via LDAP calls but then you would have to punch holes in the firewall.